# Proof of theorem on continous differentiability of the inverse function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, inverse

How can I prove the following statement?

> Consider a function $p:[c,d] \to [a,b]$ such that
>
> 1. $p \in C^1([a,b])$
> 2. $p$ is a bijection between $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$
> 3. $p'(r)\neq0$ $\,\,\,\,\forall r \in [a,b]$
>
> Then  the inverse is $C^1$ in $[c,d]$, that is $$p^{-1}:[a,b] \to [c,d] \,\,\,\,\, ,  \,\, \,\,\, p^{-1} \in C^1([c,d])$$

I would like to know in particular if all the 1.,2. and 3. conditions are used and how.

(If the notation $C^k$ is not clear see e.g. [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-kFunction.html))

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Use [the derivative of the inverse function formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation)